# Background Execution Limits and foreground service getting killed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-8.0-oreo, android-mediasession

I'm trying to play some music using code from Google's Universal Music Player plus `PlayerNotificationManager`, which is not a part of the original code (but belongs to ExoPlayer 2).

My service does `startForeground(...)` properly by a callback from `PlayerNotificationManager`:

```
    playerNotificationManager.setNotificationListener(object : PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener {
        override fun onNotificationStarted(notificationId: Int, notification: Notification?) {
            startForeground(NOW_PLAYING_NOTIFICATION, notification)
        }

        override fun onNotificationCancelled(notificationId: Int) {
        }

    })
```

And everything seems to be OK until I leave the main activity of my application with back and the service gets mercifully killed within seconds with:

```
2018-11-09 12:15:28.859 3680-3695/? W/ActivityManager: Stopping service due to app idle: u0a577 -1m19s332ms pl.qus.xenoamp2/pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.MusicService
```

The service is started properly by using

`Util.startForegroundService(...)`

So what could be possibly wrong?

Comment: Is the notification bar icon visible up until the instant the service is killed?

Comment: Yes, the notification is managed by UMP + PlayerNotificationManager and disappears because I explicitely set player to null in service onDestroy, which causes the notification to go away (that's how Google's PlayerNotificationManager works...)

Comment: Something doesn't seem right, here... `startForeground()` can't accept a `Notification` which is already being displayed. It looks to me like the library calls `onNotificationStarted()` after that notification has already been added. You need to add your _own_ notification. And you can't expect `setPlayer(null)` to clean it up for you -- the only way to remove a foreground notification is with a call to `stopForeground()`.

Comment: Might be the problem, but 1) start/stopForeground in Guugle's UAMP is managed by MediaControllerCallback depending on playback state and 2) notification is managed by PlayerNotificationManager which calls PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener when it is ready (and there i get <code>Notification</code> for <code>(Uamp)Service</code>). So how can I start foreground in PlaybackNotificationManager? I would have to pass service reference to it!

Comment: I don't have git acces here, but go to https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer and look it up in MusicService.kt. Note also that it works in UAMP, because they don't use Exo's PlayerNotificationManager and have their notification created as you said it is required to make it work.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: MediaService.kt manages the foreground state for you, so there is no need for you to ever call that.

Comment: It does, indeed. But I need ExoPlayer 2 PlayerNotificationManager to do that instead!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183371/discussion-between-greeble31-and-ssuukk).

Answer (score 1):

In the callback `onNotificationStarted` (or newly introduced `onNotificationPosted`) instead of using

```
startForeground(NOW_PLAYING_NOTIFICATION, notification)
```

you have to use the provided id

```
startForeground(notificationId, notification)
```

and when you create the notification by PlayerNotificationManager you have to make sure the `notificationId` is not `0`.